# How to detect if video is running on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, video, python-idle

I want to know the idle time of Mac. Currently I use this code

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef properties = 0;
CFTypeRef obj;
mach_port_t masterPort;
io_iterator_t iter;
io_registry_entry_t curObj;

IOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &masterPort);

/* Get IOHIDSystem */
IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, IOServiceMatching("IOHIDSystem"), &iter);
if (iter == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    curObj = IOIteratorNext(iter);
}
if (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(curObj, &properties, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) == KERN_SUCCESS && properties != NULL)
{
    obj = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, CFSTR("HIDIdleTime"));
    CFRetain(obj);
}
else
{
    return -1;
}

uint64_t tHandle = 0;
if (obj)
{
    CFTypeID type = CFGetTypeID(obj);

    if (type == CFDataGetTypeID())
    {
        CFDataGetBytes((CFDataRef) obj, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(tHandle)), (UInt8*) &tHandle);
    }
    else if (type == CFNumberGetTypeID())
    {
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)obj, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &tHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        // error
        tHandle = 0;
    }

    CFRelease(obj);

    tHandle /= 1000000; // return as milliseconds
}
else
{
    tHandle = -1;
}

CFRelease((CFTypeRef)properties);
IOObjectRelease(curObj);
IOObjectRelease(iter);
return (double)tHandle;
```

However, I want the idle time to keep 0 if any video is running.

Is there any code sample or library to check? (include video running on iTunes, VLC, youtube on browser or any other video applications)

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? OS X already has a screen saver system that multimedia apps know how to interact with, and ways to run background processes that will have low priority for CPU time and I/O bandwidth.

Comment: BTW, a simpler and *much* faster way to get the idle time is `CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, kCGAnyInputEventType)`.

Comment: @user57368 I'm developing application that work similar to lock screen. So you means that those multimedia apps will stop screensaver when it run video? Is there any method that I can check if screensaver has been stopped? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can interpret your question several ways:

**How to determine when the screensaver kicks in?**

Check the following script ([original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505519/388037)):

```
#!/bin/bash

systemSleepTimeMinutes=`pmset -g | grep "^[ ]*sleep" | awk '{ print $2 }'`

if [ $systemSleepTimeMinutes -gt "0" ]; then
    systemSleepTime=`echo "$systemSleepTimeMinutes * 60" | bc`
    devicesIdleTime=`ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print $NF/1000000000; exit}'`
    secondsBeforeSleep=`echo "$systemSleepTime - $devicesIdleTime" | bc`
    echo "Time before sleep (sec): $secondsBeforeSleep"
    exit 0
else
    echo "The system is set to not sleep."
    exit 0
fi
```

In case the screensaver is suppressed, for example by VLC, the result is:

> The system is set to not sleep.

Otherwise it returns the time until the screensaver kicks in, for example:

> Time before sleep (sec): 899.88056

Run the script above through `NSTask` or `NSAppleScript` and parse the result.
Please note "sleep" may also rever to the screensaver, depending on which one kicks in first.

**How to determine wether the screensaver is suppressed?**

The following line does the trick:

```
pmset -g | grep "^[ ]*sleep" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

In case the screensaver is suppressed it returns `0`.
Run the line above through `NSTask` or `NSAppleScript` and parse the result.

**How to suppress the screensaver?**

The official Apple documentation (including code snippet):
[How can I prevent system sleep while my application is running?](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1160.html)

---

**EDIT** *(Response to comment)*

> However, is there a built-in method that works the same as this script?

I'm not familiar with such a method. I actually doubt it exists.

Quick `NSAppleScript` example:

```
NSString *source = @"do shell script \"pmset -g | grep \\\"^[ ]*sleep\\\" | awk '{ print $2 }'\"";
NSAppleScript *script= [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSDictionary *scriptError = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor=[script executeAndReturnError:&scriptError];
if(scriptError) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",scriptError);
} else {
    if ([[descriptor stringValue] intValue] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Screensaver suppressed.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Screensaver not suppressed.");
    }
}
```

Just don't be reticent about using `NSTask` or `NSAppleScript` :)

Comment: "pmset -g | grep "^[ ]*sleep" | awk '{ print $2 }'"

That's exactly what I want! Thx. However, is there a built-in method that work the same as this script? I prefer it than the script.

Comment: Updated answer. Don't be reticent about using `NSTask` or `NSAppleScript`, they are perfectly suited for situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, watch for com.apple.screensaver.didstart  and com.apple.screensaver.didstop