# Programmatically get time until sleep (and other Energy Saver settings) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, preferences, sleep, power-management

I'd like to programmatically get the Energy Saver settings in System Preferences on Mac OS X, paticularly, the "Display Sleep" or "Computer Sleep" settings for a small app I'm writing.

[image]

I'm aware you can retrieve the sleep settings, for example, using the command line from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502138/os-x-time-until-system-display-disk-sleep)

```
 pmset -g | grep "^[ ]*sleep" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

which prints `60` (my correct sleep time), but I'd prefer to use a native API to get these settings if possible. Unfortunately, my googling so far hasn't turned up anything useful. `NSUserDefaults` was the closest I got, but I couldn't see how that could be used to get the settings I'm after.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had had several of those results turn up during my research too. A few come close, such as the IOPMLib stuff, but none seem to do what I want. I'd have thought something like this would be a well used and documented thing to do - either I'm missing something obvious or I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been over 4 years since this question was asked...  It is not clear in what language the code was desired.  Using Objective-C.

The power saver preferences are found in:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
```

From within a Mac application, we can now use:

```
NSString *powerMgt = @"/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist";
NSDictionary *power = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:powerMgt];
// for example the sleep time on AC power
NSNumber *sleepyTime = [[[power objectForKey:@"Custom Profile"] objectForKey:@"AC Power"] objectForKey:@"System Sleep Timer"];
```

with the dictionary looking like:

```
{
    ActivePowerProfiles =     {
        "AC Power" = "-1";
        "Battery Power" = "-1";
    };
    "Custom Profile" =     {
        "AC Power" =         {
            "Disk Sleep Timer" = 10;
            "Display Sleep Timer" = 10;
            "Display Sleep Uses Dim" = 1;
            GPUSwitch = 2;
            "Hibernate File" = "/var/vm/sleepimage";
            "Hibernate Mode" = 3;
            "Mobile Motion Module" = 1;
            PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep = 0;
            "Standby Delay" = 4200;
            "Standby Enabled" = 0;
            "System Sleep Timer" = 0;
            TTYSPreventSleep = 1;
            "Wake On AC Change" = 0;
            "Wake On Clamshell Open" = 1;
            "Wake On LAN" = 1;
        };
        "Battery Power" =         {
            "Disk Sleep Timer" = 10;
            "Display Sleep Timer" = 10;
            "Display Sleep Uses Dim" = 1;
            GPUSwitch = 2;
            "Hibernate File" = "/var/vm/sleepimage";
            "Hibernate Mode" = 3;
            "Mobile Motion Module" = 1;
            ReduceBrightness = 1;
            "Standby Delay" = 4200;
            "Standby Enabled" = 0;
            "System Sleep Timer" = 15;
            TTYSPreventSleep = 1;
            "Wake On AC Change" = 0;
            "Wake On Clamshell Open" = 1;
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source of [pmset](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-271.1/pmset/pmset.c.auto.html) this is what I've come up with:

```
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#define kIOPMDynamicStoreSettingsKey "State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings"
#define kIOPMSystemSleepKey "System Sleep Timer"
```

```
SCDynamicStoreRef dynamicStore = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR("get-sleep-time"), NULL, NULL);
CFDictionaryRef dictionaryRef = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, CFSTR(kIOPMDynamicStoreSettingsKey));
CFTypeRef typeRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionaryRef, CFSTR(kIOPMSystemSleepKey));

int minutes;
CFNumberGetValue(typeRef, kCFNumberIntType, (void *)&minutes);

CFRelease(dynamicStore);
CFRelease(dictionaryRef);
CFRelease(typeRef);
```

`minutes` will contain the computer sleep value in minutes.